# MySQL errno 150 with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb

So I've been getting this error when I type this in:

```
ALTER TABLE user_follow
ADD FOREIGN KEY (follower,following)
REFERENCES users(idusers)
```

But I don't get an error when I separate the follower and the following

```
ALTER TABLE user_follow
ADD FOREIGN KEY (follower)
REFERENCES users(idusers)

ALTER TABLE user_follow
ADD FOREIGN KEY (following)
REFERENCES users(idusers)
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the two keys separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you cannot reference multiple columns to one column of the other table. Below is an example on how you can define multiple compound foreign key

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4d76)